# Should the properties of a given REST resource have a consistent order?

Tags: rest, api, document, canonicalization, idempotent

RESTful `GET` requests to a given resource [should be idempotent](https://spring.io/understanding/REST#get): identical requests should always return an identical result.

How is "identical" defined here--are documents with the same properties identical, regardless of the order? Or do I need to canonicalize my response body before returning it?

Comment: I'm not sure if implementation is relevant, but I am working with JSON in the response body.

Answer (score 2):

> RESTful GET requests to a given resource should be idempotent: identical requests should always return an identical result.

In HTTP, [GET](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.1) requests to a given resource should be [*safe*](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.2.1), which is to say that it is read-only, which is trivially idempotent.

```
no-op(X) === X

therefore

no-op(no-op(X)) === no-op(X)
QED.
```

*Safe* and *idempotent* are describing the side effects of the request on the server; they don't constrain the representation returned by the resource in any way.

For instance, the [Online UUID Generator Tool](https://www.uuidgenerator.net/) resource returns an html page with different content each time send it a GET request.  The request is safe (it doesn't modify the resource), and therefore idempotent, even though the representation returned isn't *stable*.